# Please explain the high level architecture of Hadoop Cluster Environment?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, bigdata

Since am new to Hadoop Administration, am trying to understanding the Hadoop Cluster Setup Environment in real Time Production systems.

1) As of today, do most projects run on Hadoop v1 or Hadoop v2 ?

2) Do we have Single Cluster or Multiple Clusters for a single Projects?
(I heard there are multiple clusters where each cluster is dedicated to specific roles.)

3) Do the Hadoop Clusters usually run on Cloud like AWS, Rackspace or Do they run on their Clien't own network.?

Comment: Please read about [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [things to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All questions you've completely depends on the client, project and lot of other factors.. but here are my 2 cents

1) Most of the projects have been switched to Hadoop v2.

2) It depends, obviously there will be 1 or 2 envs for dev, test and staging etc., before production. But in production one project will have one environment or one environment handles multiple projects. (Yahoo has 4,500 node hadoop cluster)

3) Number of nodes varies on the amount of data the company handles.. there are companies which run production cluster on 4 node cluster and 4000 node cluster

4) Again it depends on the type of data they're storing and processing.. clients with sensitive information like Banking won't normally go for Cloud as they feel data will be secure in their own data centers. But some clients they completely go for cloud because they save a lot of money (like New York Times on AWS).

Comment: Thanks Raj for your valuable inputs